# Use string variable as object key

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resource-qualifiers

I have strings in my strings.xml e.g.:

```
<string name="category__service">Service</string>
```

I want to access them like this:

```
val key = "category__$this.name" // "category__service"
val s = R.string.[key]
```

This would give me the Id of the string which I can use.
But this way I get the error

> The expression cannot be a selector (occur after a doted text)

I also tried

```
val s = R.string.$key
```

but I get:

> Expecting an element

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/R) on what R is to begin with, isn't giving me much. As far as I see – R.string does not have a simple getter.

So at this point I'm just guessing for a solution. Is this even possible in Kotlin?

Comment: From the link, I'm guessing this is a question about the Android API; if so, adding a suitable tag to the question, and/or mentioning that explicitly, might help provide some context.  Also, it might help to explain what this code is intended to do.

Comment: R is not a repository of data.  It is just a list of pointers.  It is used for finding objects and does not contain any data from those objects.  In your example above, leave off the $.  It should already be a property if it is that file.  R.String.category__service would access that one.  If you want selectables you need to create xml arrays inside the strings file and access them properly as arrays.

Comment: @JohnLord leaving off the $ would not work since I have multiple categories and I wanted to walk trough them and I didn't want to hardcode R.string.category__service, R.string.category__other etc. I have looked at xml arrays in the documentation and it seems you can't acces them by key - meaning their key is numeric. But I'd need something like category['service']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following:

```
val key = "category__$this.name" // "category__service"
val s = resources.getIdentifier(key, "string", context.packageName)
```